# How to get proxy server ip

Tags: proxy, netstat

Let say you have to setup proxy setting in some app, but you don't know the proxy server IP and/or port. The browser setting says: automatic detection. 
And there is no one around to give you the answer.
How to obtain the proxy server ip address

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't done so, please take a [tour]! I'm afraid I'm not quite sure what you are asking in your question: could you please give more information on your problem and what you want to do? Do you want the proxy server IP of your own configuration? Of a remote app?

Answer (score 1):

Go to cmd or powershell
run netstat
you will see a lot and a lot more connections. 
The output shows columns like below:

'Protocol' 'Local Address' 'Foreign Address' 'State'

Foreign Address will repeat the same value many, many times. This is your proxy server for 99%. if there is only name simply ping the name to get the ip address.

4ex:
proxy:8080

ping proxy

proxy.mynetwork.local
10.0.0.250

setup the proxy in your app to
proxy server:
proxy.mytwork.local (or 10.0.0.250)

proxy port: 8080

Answer (score 0):

try this list of servers here:

https://www.us-proxy.org/

or here:

https://whatismyipaddress.com/google-search?q=proxy+server+list&sa=Proxy+Server+List+Search&cx=013731333855297778374%3Absyy_h6slhu&cof=FORID%3A9&ie=ISO-8859-1